# {Required] Attribute is not working on Lists ASP.NET WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, attributes, required

Here's my model

```
 public class TaskForUpdateDTO
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and my controller

```
    [HttpPut]
    public ActionResult<List<TaskDTO>> Put([FromBody] List<TaskForUpdateDTO> tasks )
    {
        List<TaskBO> tasksForUpdate = TaskForUpdateDTO.MapToBOList(tasks);
        tasksForUpdate = _serviceManager.TaskService.Update(tasksForUpdate);

        if (tasksForUpdate is null) return NotFound();

        return Ok(TaskDTO.MapToDTOList(tasksForUpdate));
    }
```

and body of my request

```
    [{
    "Name":"Do Laundry",
    "UserId":1
     },
     {
    "Name":"Wash Dishes",
    "UserId":1
    }]
```

when sending a PUT request, I'm not getting a 400 error , which I should because I'm not sending the Id of the item.

how can I fix this?

Comment: It seems that there is a typo in your TaskForUpdateDTO class you pasted ;)

Comment: @DylanBarquilla yeah because I took out some of the fields for brevity. but it has nothing to do with the problem .

Comment: @YongShun yeah it makes me understand where the issue is, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Required` Attribute only check for null.
The Default value of an `int` is simply "0"(zero). So, it is not null when `Required` attribute check it.

If you Prefer to use the `Required` attribute then replace your `int` to `int?` (Nullable int. The Default Value of Nullable int is `null` And can double-Check with it's static `.HasValue()` method)

Or if you need to check that not pass the value when value is Zero or Less then you can use `Range` Attribute

Usage of `Range Attribute` :

```
[Range(1, Int32.MaxValue)]
public int Id {get;set;}
```

Simply you can change the `Int32.MaxValue` to your Maximum acceptable integer of your needs.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

yes, it is correct behavior, because required is cheking that this property is not null, but you need to check that this property is unique.
For example:
[Custom validation unique property - generic classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32172157/custom-validation-unique-property-generic-classes)